# passive Gerunds construction being+past participle

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the meanings of following sentence pairs:

1. I like being obeyed by my students.
   I like to be obeyed by my students.
2. I don't like being laughed at me.
   I don't like to be laughed at me.
3. I don't like being asked irrelevant questions.
   I don't like to be asked irrelevant questions.

Could you please tell me about the "being+past participle" form related to gerunds? Is it the passive of the -ing form ? If so, how would the sentences look like in active form?